How do I intercept a logging method before its argument is passed in?
I'm working in a Java project where I'm trying to use Spring AOP to create a logger that masks PII data (Personally Identifiable Information). The approach is to have something declarative. Following some tutorials, I came up with an annotation that is used to demarcate PII data:
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Confidential {
}

I have a POJO where the getter method is annotated with the @Confidential type:
public class PiiPojo {
    @Confidential
    private String secretName;
    ... other fields here ...

    @Confidential
    public String getSecretName() {
        return secretName;
    }
}

My Aspect looks like this:
@Aspect
public class PIILoggerAspect {
    @Around("execution(* org.slf4j.Logger.*(..))")
    public Object piiMasker(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        var joinPointArgs = joinPoint.getArgs();
        // ... PII masking stuff here ...

        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}

The code that does the logging is using a delegating "veneer" over the slf4j Logger interface since trying to use the default from the org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger() results in a CGLIB error as the implementation class is final.
The code that does the logging uses the delegating logger to log information like this:
// Log information from the PII POJO
public void someMethod(PiiPojo pojo) {
    log.info("Passing in secret name: {}", pojo.getSecretName());
}

The aspect intercepts the call properly, but the getter has already been called on the POJO, so I'm just getting the String value from pojo.getSecretName(), and I don't know if that's the data I'm supposed to mask vs just any random String that someone passes to the logger. I've tried modifying the expression in the aspect to also take into account the annotation, but as soon as I do that, the aspect no longer intercepts the call to log.info(). Example:
@Around("execution(* org.slf4j.Logger.*(..)) && @annotation(Confidential)")

and
@Around("@annotation(confidential) && execution(* org.slf4j.Logger.*(..))")
public Object piiMasker(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Confidential confidential) throws Throwable {


The logging veneer looks something like this:
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.Marker;

public class MyLogger implements org.slf4j.Logger {
    private final Logger log;

    public MyLogger(Logger log) {
        this.log = log;
    }

    public void info(String msg) {
        log.info(msg);
    }

    ... other methods here ...
}

I don't seem to get any errors regarding the expression, but the aspect intercepting method just doesn't get called anymore as soon as I add the && @annotation. I've tried with and without the package part of the annotation type in the expression, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Some other details:

The Aspect is created in a Spring @Configuration annotated config file as a @Bean.
The config file is annotated with @EnableAspectJAutoProxy.
The "veneer" logger is created using a @Bean and passed in via constructor injection to the class where it's used.

Ideally, what I would want is to intercept any method call to the logger, but only in the context of the @Confidential annotation.

You mention a veneer, but your sample codes does not match your description, trying to directly intercept org.slf4j.Logger.*(..). This cannot even work with Spring AOP, you would need native AspectJ for it. Please edit the question to make the code match the description, or, even better, simply post a minimal reproducer on GitHub.

Define “PII data”.

@kriegaex I added the important parts of the veneer to the post. I have tried intercepting both the veneer logger, and slf4j. There wasn't really a difference that I could see. This expression seems to work the same as if I specify the veneer logger:
@Around("execution(* org.slf4j.Logger.*(..))")

@BasilBourque PII stands for "Personally Identifiable Information". I wanted to keep my post as terse as possible, so I didn't go into details about it. It's a well known industry acronym. I edited the post and wrote it out.

@kriegaex I started off using straight up AspectJ, but I'm also using Lombok in my project, and they didn't seem to get along. Getting rid of Lombok isn't an option in my case, so if I can get this to work with Spring AOP, that's my preference.

SO is not a discussion forum. Like I said, either you use AspectJ and can intercept SLF4J directly or Spring AOP and cannot, necessitating what you call a "veneer", i.e. a Spring AOP component you can intercept. Both are fundamentally different, not "not really a difference" as you said. What your code shows cannot work in Spring AOP. Maybe, you use native AspectJ in load-time weaving mode without being aware of it. The MCVE would show me. Provide one or help yourself. It is not up to you to decide what is necessary or essential for others to help you.

Please understand that other people want to actually run your code to reproduce the situation and then be able to help you. The devil is in the details. I do not have a Java or AspectJ compiler + and emulator to run Spring projects in my head. Do you? I do not need the original code, just a simplified, anonymised version of the project reproducing the problem.
